# Qué significan los caracteres de "?" y ":" en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

¿Alguien sabe que significa esto en JavaScript? especificamente el `?` y `:`

```
n = self.isUploadable ? fileStack.length : numFiles,
```

Comment: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2013/05/16/les-bases/

Comment: operador ternario, puedes mirar [aquí][1] su estructura y como funciona. [1]:https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### [Operador condicional (ternario)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator)

Que es una forma más corta de la estructura "if else".

Por ejemplo

```
var result = 6%2==0 ? "Even" : "Odd";
```

Es lo mismo que

```
if(6%2==0){
     result = "Even";
}
else{
     result = "Odd";
}
```

por lo que en tu ejemplo

```
if(self.isUploadable){
    n = fileStack.length;
}
else{
     n = numFiles;
}
```

Comment: No es totalmente equivalente: el resultado de `<condicion> ? <expresion-verdadera> : <expresion-falsa>` es una *expresión* mientras que `if .. else` simplemente es un *statement*

Comment: No es una forma de acortar if-else porque a diferencia de este el operador ternario devuelve siempre un valor por ser una expresion. Lastima que hay personas confundidas por el sobrevoto de esto, sobretodo el que acepto la publicacion.

Comment: A mi siempre se me olvida como se llama ese operador, pero es muy útil, en python y en c++ se usan de forma fácil, bueno, en python es aún más fácil.

Answer (score 31):

Esa sintáxis es de **JavaScript** y corresponde al [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator):

> condicion ? expresion1 : expresion2

**Ejemplos:**

```
> var mayor = 4 > 5 ? "Si" : "No";
> mayor
"No"
> var mayor = 100000 > 0 ? true : false;
> mayor
true
> var mayor = array1.length > array2.length ? hacerAlgo() : hacerOtraCosa();
```

Ten en cuenta que en el último ejemplo tanto `hacerAlgo()` y `hacerOtraCosa()` deberían retornar algo que tenga sentido según el contexto bajo el cual estás trabajando.

Dado que los operadores ternarios son expresiones en JavaScript, es posible usarlos de esta forma, por ejemplo:

```
> var masculino = false;
> var saludo = "Hola " + (masculino ? "chico" : "chica") + ", ¿cómo estás?";
> saludo
"Hola chica, ¿cómo estás?"
```

Su contraparte usando la sentencia `if {} else {}` sería:

```
var masculino = false;
var saludo = "Hola ";
if (masculino) {
    saludo += "chico";
} else {
    saludo += "chica";
}
saludo += ", ¿cómo estás?";
```

Si, te ahorras algunas líneas de código.

Repondiendo tus preguntas, `?` simplemente evalúa la condición que está a la izquierda y `:` es simplemente el separador entre las expresiones que son evaluadas según el resultado de la condición.

### Nota:

No confundir [operador ternario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) con el [operador Elvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator).

Comment: `No confundir operador ternario con el operador Elvis.` El operador Elvis no existe en JavaScript, ¿verdad?

Comment: @PeterOlson asi es, no existe en JavaScript. Es mas que nada una nota para la gente con background en PHP, por ejemplo, que pueden estar acostumbrados a usarlo ya que la sintáxis es similar usando `?` y `:`

Answer (score 3):

Si se diera el caso de que `isUploadable` es `true` solo cuando `fileStack` contenga datos, entonces esto también te serviría

```
n = fileStack.length || numFiles;
```

Recuerda que:

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `false`
- `0`
- `''` (string empty)

son `false` para JavaScript.

Answer (score -2):

Es un if else se puede usar tanto en javascript como en PHP

```
$variable = ($var_1 == $var_2 )?valor si es cierto:valor si es falso;
```