# Diferencias entre el operador Elvis ?: y el operador coalescente nulo

Tags: operador

Leyendo [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2130/qu%C3%A9-significan-los-caracteres-de-y-en-javascript) me encontré una referencia al llamado [operador Elvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) (link en inglés) o `?:` que es muy parecido al operador `||` usado en javascript o también llamado [operador de coalescencia nula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) (link en ingles).

Investigando más sobre ambos no logré distingir ninguna diferencia entre ellos lo que me llevó a preguntarme, ¿Realmente existe alguna diferencia? Si no la hay ¿Entonces porque hay dos referencias a algo que semánticamente significa lo mismo?

Ejemplos del operador elvis

```
var variable = foo ?: bar
```

Devuelve `foo` si `foo` existe y no es nulo sino devuelve `bar`

Operador coalescente nulo

```
var variable = foo || bar
```

que hace exactamente lo mismo

Nota: El operador elvis no es parte del lenguaje javascript, en su lugar se encuentra el [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: ...pero el operador "Elvis" no existe en JavaScript!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambos se comportan iguales, pero la diferencia esta en que lenguajes lo estas usando.

Por ejemplo el `Elvis Operator` no esta disponible en `Javascript`, ya que para eso tenemos el `||` o double pipe.

En cambio, en PHP por ejemplo no se tiene el || para realizar Operador coalescente nulo y por esto se usa el `?:`, simplemene un `if ternario` o en su defecto el `??`.

Si miras el Articulo de Wikipedia que colocas, y miras los lenguajes que es usado el `Elvis Operator` solo aparecen. `C`, `Groovy` y `PHP`

Comment: En PHP existen tanto el operador Elvis como un operador coalescente nulo representado por el símbolo `??` lo que vuelve aún mas confusa la presencia de ambos operadores.

Comment: ya actualizo la respuesta, pensé que con colocar que el doble pipe no se tiene para ese fin era mas que suficiente.

Comment: Inicialmente pensé que el operador elvis no hacía cortocircuito y que ahí podía radicar la diferencia pero gracias a [este post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993409/operator-the-elvis-operator-in-php) veo que ambos se comportan exactamente igual en ese sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Si `a = false`,

```
a ?? 'x'  ->  a
a || 'x'  ->  x
```

En algunos lenguajes hay varios valores *falsos* (usualmente son `false`, `null`, `0`, `""`, lista vacía, etc.). El operador de coalescencia nula devolvería esos valores si están del lado izquierdo (excepto con `null`, claro), mientras que el operador Elvis devolvería los del otro lado.