# ¿Cuál es el error de esta función?

Tags: javascript, operador-ternario

```js
(function(){
    Math.sqrt(25) == 5 ? return true : return false;
})();
```

Solo quiero retornar `true` si la raíz de `25` da `5`, y si no retornar `false`.

Comment: ¿ Existe la posibilidad que retorne `false`? ;) , además recomendaría leer una  [pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2130/qu%C3%A9-significan-los-caracteres-de-y-en-javascript/2131#2131)

Comment: Además de como dice @Dev.Joel esa condición siempre será `true` no entiendo el `return`, un operador ternario siempre devuelve un valor así que con poner `true` y `false` sería suficiente. Corregidme si me equivoco.

Comment: @Dev.Joel @blonfu Es irrelevante que siempre retorne `true`, @Eduardo no está preguntando por eso. El problema es que la función se ejecuta con errores pues el return debe estar por fuera del operador, y no contenido en las ramas

Comment: @Piyin si tienes una respuesta acertada, debes añadirla en la sección respuestas. Sé lo que pregunta el OP y además un error lógico nunca  es irrelevante.

Comment: @Dev.Joel La respuesta correcta ya la dio Javier Pintor. Eso no es un error lógico, se podría simplificar, claro, pero no es un error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se soluciona extrayendo el `return` de las opciones del operador ternario, y poníendolo fuera devolviendo el resultado del operador ternario (como ya te ha respondido @JavierPintor en la otra respuesta).

La causa del error es debida a que el operador ternario, al ser un operador, no es exactamente como una sentencia condicional `if`. Como es un operador tiene que devolver un valor, obteniendo dicho valor de una de las opciones posibles a ambos lados de `:`. Estas posibles opciones deben ser expresiones (combinación de operadores y operandos) que serán evaluadas a un valor en caso de ser elegidas dependiendo del resultado de la condición. Por lo tanto, como `return` no forma una expresión que se evalúe a un valor, no es admitida.

Así es la solución:

```
(function() {
    return Math.sqrt(25) == 5 ? true : false;
})();
```

Pero, en los casos como éste, donde devuelves `true` o `false` dependiendo del resultado de una comparación, lo óptimo es que devuelvas directamente el resultado de la comparación que se evalúa a `true` o `false`. Así te evitas el operador ternario:

```
(function() {
    return Math.sqrt(25) == 5;
})();
```

Answer (score 9):

El return lo debes poner al principio de la siguiente manera:

```
(function(){
  return (Math.sqrt(25)==5 ? true : false);
})();
```