# De que otra forma podríamos escribir este fragmento de código en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var cal = parseInt(prompt("Digite la Calificacion del alumno: "));

if(cal<0 || cal>10){
    alert("Recuerde que la calificacion debe de estar entre 0 y 10");

    cal = parseInt(prompt("Digite NUEVAMENTE la Calificacion del alumno: "));

    if(cal>8){
         alert("Aprobado");
     }else{
         alert("NO Aprobo");
     }
}else if(cal>8){
         alert("Aprobado");
 }else{
     alert("NO Aprobo");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Para validar las entradas , un `do while` y para la impresión de datos un [operador ternario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2130/qu%C3%A9-significan-los-caracteres-de-y-en-javascript/2133#2133) , aunque si son calificaciones también sería necesario trabajar con decimales. `parseFloat`

```js
var cal =0;
do
    cal = parseFloat(prompt("Digite la Calificacion del alumno: "))
while(cal<0 || cal>10);
alert((cal>8)?"Aprobado":"Desaprobado");
```

Comment: Super tu comentario, gracias, como estoy en estos momentos recordando un poco todo el tema de la programación y de como funcionan las estructuras condicionales, escribí ese fragmento y tengo la duda si utilizando las mismas estructuras se puede escribir de una forma diferente sin necesitar tantas lineas de código.

Comment: @JairoCuartas perfecto, no olvidar si una respuesta resolvió su problema o despejo dudas marcarla como aceptada. Saludos